# D3 How to only visualize visible nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say I make a force layout graph, however the graph has hundreds of nodes which make the visualization slow. Let's say I want to zoom in on a part of the graph. Does D3 not draw the visible parts of the graph?

How do I basically only do the calculations for part of the graph that is visible while caching the nearby nodes so that if someone pans on the visualization, the nearby nodes would be generated faster.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will have to find the startX, startY, endX and endY(Calculate using panX, panY from zoom behavior) points of the visible area and check if the nodes bounding box is inside visible area. Apply operations on filtered result of nodes.

Comment: That means I would have to somehow keep track of the coordinates. Looping through all the nodes would be slow. I'm thinking a tree structure?

Comment: Use a [quadtree](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom).